# akka http remote address

Tags: scala, unit-testing, http, akka

I'm using Akka HTTP 10.0.9, but struggling to get my unit tests to have a working Remote Address.

eg unit test:

```
Get("/").withHeaders(
    RawHeader("Remote-Address", "192.168.1.1"), RawHeader("X-Forwarded-For", "192.168.1.1")
) ~> route ~> check {
    status must_== StatusCodes.OK
}
```

And in the web server code:

```
extractClientIP{ clientAddr =>
  complete(s"$clientAddr")
}
```

When running the app via the command line, the client address is returned correctly. But when run via unit tests, the client address always comes back as "Unknown"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by **akka http** can't handle the `RawHeader` in **test**. You can solve it by use the `Remote-Address` object for set the **IP** for test:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.headers.`Remote-Address`
Get().withHeaders(
  `Remote-Address`(RemoteAddress(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.1.1", 23)))
)
```

Comment: Now that Remote-Address is deprecated how would we set this is RawHeader is not handled by akka-http-test?

Comment: hi @colinbes, I am not using on akka now, maybe you can create a new question about this problem